# Unable to write in the "/var/www/html/public/uploads" directory problem when using docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Unable to write in the "/var/www/html/public/uploads" directory
can you help me with this in laravel
i use docker and i see this when i was uploading image

when not using docker it works well but in docker i have this problem

Answer (score -2):

You need to give directory permission

```
`chmod -R 777 ./directory`
```

Comment: This is almost always a significant security mistake.